Traefik 2 fallback default router to Caddy
I'm using Traefik 2.11 and I'd like to forward all unmatched traffic to another reverse proxy (namely Caddy).
First question, is it possible to define a router with no rule ? (which would get a 0 priority) Is it going to sweep all the remaining traffic ?
Second question, will I be able to also delegate the SSL offloading to Caddy since I'm already redirecting the 80.
And lastly:
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: "websecure"
          scheme: "https"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

http:
  routers:
    fallback:
      service: fallback
      entrypoints: web
  services:
    fallback:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://caddy-ip"

This doesn't seem to do the job, it's still trying to do the TLS handshake, I guess because it's getting redirected before reaching my fallback router
